# The android sdk requires the new build tools component to be installed

Tags: sdk, installation, build-error, build-tools

Whenever I try to install the build tools, it gives many errors and says nothing was installed.

I recently installed eclipse and adt and sdk.

I am using eclipse mars, windows 10 os 64 bit. Please help
Thank you

the error is as follows:-

```
$Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 23
Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23
Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp
Downloading SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1
Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp
Downloading Samples for SDK API 23, revision 2
Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp
Downloading Sources for Android SDK, API 23, revision 1
Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp
Downloading Android Support Library, revision 23
Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp
Downloading Google USB Driver, revision 11
Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp
Skipping 'Android TV ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 23, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 23, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 23, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android API 23, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 23, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 23, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image, Google Inc. API 23, revision 7'; it depends on 'Google APIs, Android API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Google Inc. API 23, revision 7'; it depends on 'Google APIs, Android API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Google Inc. API 23, revision 7'; it depends on 'Google APIs, Android API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Done. Nothing was installed.
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 23
Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23
Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp
Downloading SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1
Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp
Downloading Samples for SDK API 23, revision 2
Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp
Downloading Sources for Android SDK, API 23, revision 1
Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp
Downloading Android Support Library, revision 23
Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp
Downloading Google USB Driver, revision 11
Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp
Skipping 'Android TV ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 23, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 23, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 23, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android API 23, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 23, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 23, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image, Google Inc. API 23, revision 7'; it depends on 'Google APIs, Android API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Google Inc. API 23, revision 7'; it depends on 'Google APIs, Android API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Google Inc. API 23, revision 7'; it depends on 'Google APIs, Android API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Done. Nothing was installed.
```

Comment: Please format properly the error message using the tags (see help button), otherwise you will get downoted and no one will answer your question ...